# Gearman function is not getting dropped and it displaying error

Tags: php, gearman

Gearman function is not getting dropped and it displaying the below error.

Error: there are still connected workers or executing clients

from gearadmin --status it shows
function_name_one  0       0       112

so 112 worker are ther available for work so may be thats why function is not dropped.

so can any one help me how to resoleve this?
how to remove workers?

Answer (score 1):

You can only drop workers when they are not running. You have the process running in the background.

I use htop to search for the process and then kill it. Can you run this command

```
ps aux | grep function_name_one
```

To check the pid's of your workers so you can kill them.